# Checkbox into an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm dynamically populating data into a jQuery accordion.

```
<div id="checkbox">
  <h2>
    <span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="apple" />
    </span>
    Text 1
  </h2>
  <div> content 1 </div>
</div>
```

I've placed a checkbox next to each header.

```
$("#accordianParent").accordion({
      collapsible: true,active: false
});

$(document).on('click', '.mycheck', function(ev){ 
        ev.stopPropagation(); 
        console.log("clicked!");
});
```

When clicked on a checkbox, how can I make the checkbox check and prevent the accordion from expanding?

When I use my code, console outputs the `clicked!` correctly. But the accordion expands and the check mark does not appear. How to fix this?

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkksrtre/)

Comment: the problem is you are using a delegate, you need the `change` event directly on the checkbox.

Comment: @BenG Thank you. I tried `$('.mycheck').change(function(){ console.log("clicked!");  });` But it's the same. How can this be fixed?

Comment: try `ev.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: show where you are populating dynamically. you need to add the change after that.

Comment: use `$('.mycheck').change(function(ev){ ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); console.log("clicked!"); });`.

Comment: @BenG Thanks again. That doesn't work either Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkksrtre/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkksrtre/2/)

```
$('.mycheck').click( function(ev){ // add a direct event
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); // this stops from other handlers to execute and stop event bubbling
        console.log("clicked!");
});
```